# Implementing a login system with re-frame

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

I am new to re-frame and not quite sure how to build a user authentication/authorization system with it.

From what I gathered I should create an auth `interceptor` and place my auth logic inside `:before` section then inject the interceptor into every events `reg-event-db` and `reg-event-fx` that I want to protect.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if my solution is particularly idiomatic, but I used something like the following in one of my projects. Consider it a Works For Me.

Create a map for the ajax request with a special value for error cases (ignore the `context-uri` function):

```
(defn xhrio-map [method path format success-event]
  {:method          method
   :uri             (context-uri path)
   :timeout         5000
   :response-format format
   :on-success      [success-event]
   :on-failure      [::ajax-failure]})
```

Then I use an fx handler for the failure (this is a bit more complicated as it also handles a loading indicator):

```
(rf/reg-event-fx
 ::ajax-failure
 (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ http-result]]
   (if (= 403 (:status http-result))
     {:db (assoc db :loading-indicator nil)
      :dispatch [::logout]}
     {:db (assoc db :loading-indicator nil)
      :dispatch
      [::error-msg (str "Error fetching from " (:uri http-result)
                        ": " (:response http-result))]})))
```

The `::logout` events sets the document location. This also triggers the logout in the backend.

```
(rf/reg-event-fx
 ::logout
 (fn [coefx [ev]]
   {::location "./logout"}))
```

Finally, the loading of resources works like this:

```
 (defn load-with-indicator [db xhrio-data]
  {:db (assoc db :loading-indicator true)
   :http-xhrio xhrio-data})

(rf/reg-event-fx
 ::load-documentation
 (fn [{:keys [db]} _]
   (load-with-indicator
    db
    (xhrio-map :get "documentation/"
               (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
               ::received-documentation))))
```

The `:received-documentation` is handled by some code which invokes the correct display functions.

This uses the  [day8.re-frame/http-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx) and `ajax.core`

On the backend, I use something similar to the demo code I published over at https://github.com/ska2342/ring-routes-demo.

Hope that helps.

### License of the code in this post

In addition to the default license of the StackOverflow site, I also publish these lines under the Eclipse Public License either version 1.0 or (at your option) any later version.